# hierarchy tree recursive count (maximum recursion depth exceeded)

Tags: python, graph, tree

This is an example of a possible tree in my data.
The data consist of 0.5 mil rows.
I am suppose to count the average number of internal nodes (circled) across the whole data set which has many of such trees.

- for A there are 4 internal nodes.
- for C there are 2 internal nodes. etc.

[image]

I have learned that you can use recursion but it quickly reach Recursion error.

```
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

So i modify it with an lru cache code i found on stackoverflow but theres another problem too.

Here is a snippet of the data:

```
   name employee
0   A   B
1   A   C
2   B   D
3   C   E
4   C   F
5   E   H
6   E   I
7   H   T
8   H   U
9   H   V
```

Here are the codes i have.

```
#collapse to dictionary
em = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
dict_a = {k: set(g["employee"].tolist()) for k,g in em.groupby("name")}

output dict_a:
{'A': {'B', 'C'},
 'B': {'D'},
 'C': {'E', 'F'},
 'E': {'H', 'I'},
 'H': {'T', 'U', 'V'}}

import sys
import functools


def hash_dict(func):
    """Transform mutable dictionnary
    Into immutable
    Useful to be compatible with cache
    """
    class HDict(dict):
        def __hash__(self):
            return hash(frozenset(self.items()))

    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        args = tuple([HDict(arg) if isinstance(arg, dict) else arg for arg in args])
        kwargs = {k: HDict(v) if isinstance(v, dict) else v for k, v in kwargs.items()}
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapped

#MY ACTUAL FUNCTION#
@hash_dict
@lru_cache(128)
def interior_nodes_from(tree, node):
    if node in tree: #key of interest in dict
        for child in tree[node]: # for values in the key, dict indexing
            if child in tree: #if the values is key
                yield child #keys
                yield from interior_nodes_from(tree, child) #recursive
                
              
#assign to df
key= []
value=[]

def recur(dic):
    for k in dict_a:
        key.append(k)
        value.append(len(list(interior_nodes_from(dict_a, k))))

recur(dict_a)
```

Now with the lru cache code, i get this error.

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-56-9282afd81500> in <module>
----> 1 recur(dict_a)

<ipython-input-55-ebf6465e872c> in wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
     28         args = tuple([HDict(arg) if isinstance(arg, dict) else arg for arg in args])
     29         kwargs = {k: HDict(v) if isinstance(v, dict) else v for k, v in kwargs.items()}
---> 30         return func(*args, **kwargs)
     31     return wrapped
     32 

<ipython-input-55-ebf6465e872c> in recur(dic)
     51     for k in dic:
     52         key.append(k)
---> 53         value.append(len(list(interior_nodes_from(dic, k))))

<ipython-input-55-ebf6465e872c> in interior_nodes_from(tree, node)
     39             if child in tree: #if the values is key
     40                 yield child #keys
---> 41                 yield from interior_nodes_from(tree, child) #recursive
     42 
     43 

ValueError: generator already executing
```

Is there a better way or a package or even a non-recursive way to do this in python?

Answer (score 0):

Networkx is a great package for dealing with graphs. You can use it to create a tree representing your data, then for some node in the tree you can count it's neighbors, then count the neighbors of its neighbors to see which of them are internal and which are external. I think networkx comes included with conda

```py
import networkx as nx
import csv

# make a list of edges instead of a dict
edges = []
with open("test.csv", newline='') as file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(file)
    for row in reader:
        edges.append((row['name'], row['employee']))

# create the graph and add edges
graph = nx.DiGraph()
graph.add_edges_from(edges)

# if you want to see the graph, just do nx.draw(graph) (be careful if
# there's a lot of data. It might take a long time)

# this function will take some node
# and the current total number of internal nodes,
# then return the final total
def countInternals(node, total):
    
    # get the neighbors of node
    neighbors = graph.neighbors(node)
    
    for n in neighbors:
        
        # get the neighbors of n
        n_neighbors = list(graph.neighbors(n))
        
        # if n has more than 0 neighbors, it must be internal, so we 
        # add to total, then count the internals of n
        if len(n_neighbors) > 0:
            total += 1
            total = countInternals(n, total)
        
        else:
            return total
    
    return total

countInternals('A', 0)
>>> 4
```

Now `total` should equal `node`'s neighbors that are internal nodes

EDIT: I'm not sure why F isn't an internal node in the picture you posted. My code would have counted it, but I think you get the idea anyway.

EDIT: I changed the code block to count *all* internal nodes that are children of the given node

Comment: Hey, thank you for helping. F is not internal as it does not have children. So i want to exclude all the nodes that do not have children. Any networkx tutorial to recommend me?

Comment: [here are the docs](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/introduction.html).  I don't know of any other sources, sorry.

Comment: I made a couple other edits to the code block that make it work better with your data snippet

Comment: the answer do not seem right as this will output 2 for A but A has 4 children that are not leaf nodes.

Comment: I changed the code block so it should do what you want now. Sorry about that.